# Change IAP Display Name

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Is there any way to change an In App Purchase display name after you've created the IAP?

I see the option to change other items, just not that... am I missing something?

Thanks!

This is referring to the Display Name in iTunes Connect when you add an IAP item.

Comment: Could you please improve your question by adding a bit more context to it. As it is now it is pretty hard to guess what are you asking exactly I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it looks like you can't, just double click Display Name to edit